# Need help making a ground distance detector

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a data pack where some players cannot take fall damage. I don't want to use resistance 5 or jump boost 255 as there needs to be PVP and jump boost 255 will launch you in the air with PVP.

My solution is to calculate the amount of fall damage that will be taken. e.g 5 blocks, one heart, and add that on to their existing health with the `/attribute` command. However, I cannot find any tutorials on how to detect this distance. Can anybody link a multiplayer-friendly tutorial or give a better solution?

TL;DR: Need no fall damage solution for one specific person in multiplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them boots enchanted with a high level of feather falling (or, if you want them to be able to use their own armor, run a command to enchant whatever boots they wear with a high level of feather falling).

Answer (score 2):

Since players can't jump while in the air, you can use a command block to give players them the jump boost effect only while in the air, where it will reduce fall damage but have no impact on jumping. To do this, run these commands every tick:

```
/effect give @a[...,nbt={OnGround:0b}] jump_boost 1 255
/effect clear @a[...,nbt={OnGround:1b}] jump_boost
```

Comment: The problem with that is that if a player is hit while in the air w jump boost 255 they yeet in the air and that is very gameplay impacting

Comment: You could use resistance instead of jump boost in that case; this would make people immune to damage while in the air, which would be a relatively minor side effect (how often do people get hit while in the air?)

Comment: It will have lots of pvp and i dont want to give such an advantage